# LayerSlider getting blurb/jerk while change to second slide

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider, slide

I'm developing my client demo site, I've a issue on layerslider when first slide change to second one so it's blurb/jerk i'm sure i miss some setting on it please advise.

pc.iwebcrux.com

Thank's
Saad A.

Comment: Please always post your code within the question body, describe what is not working as expected and if possible provide in a demo in a Sandbox like jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

The link that you shared is unlinkable...
But my best guess is that you have imported a demo json slider for the layer slider..
If you delete the slider and re import it, it will work smooth...